# Element will not show with jQuery inside of a change event

Tags: jquery

With the following code, the `$('#parsing-notice').show();` code does not show the element.

```
    $('#import').change(function (e) {
        $('#parsing-notice').show();
        e.preventDefault();
        var form = $(this).closest('form');
        form.submit();
        return false;
    });
```

But with the following timeout, it does show.

```
    $('#import').change(function (e) {
        $('#parsing-notice').show();
        e.preventDefault();
        var form = $(this).closest('form');
        setTimeout(function () {
            form.submit();
         }, 1000);
        return false;
    });
```

Note that `form.submit();` has `e.preventDefault()` too, so the page is not reloaded.

The submit event is as follows;

```
$('form[name="tournaments"]').submit(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var formData = new FormData(this);
    $.ajax({
        url: '/',
        type: 'POST',
        data: formData,
        async: false,
        success: function (data) {

        },
        cache: false,
        contentType: false,
        processData: false
    });
    return false;
});
```

Why does it not show in the first example?

Comment: Is the page reloading when you submit the form?  I imagine everything that's being processed on the page would end when a new page load is occurring.

Comment: Ah no, it's not reloaded. See edit.

Comment: Can you provide a complete and demonstrable example?

Comment: Hi David, I have updated my question

Comment: I imagine the problem is with the async: false of the ajax call. I remember somewhere in the past this issue happening... can you try to remove that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The async property of the object passed to $.ajax() method is by default true.

Being async means method will not block the execution of the script. When set to false, it will.

Most likely it's that that is preventing the show() from running.

Comment: Perfect! Makes sense now!